# SOLVED: useState updates but component does not re-render

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state

I am using `useSWR` to fetch updates from a server.

```
const {data, error} = useSWR('url', url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()), { refreshInterval: 1000 })
```

The server return:

```
{
  "values": {
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080
  }
}
```

Then I am using `useEffect` to update local state like this:

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  if(data) {
    setWidth(data.values.width)
    setHeight(data.values.height)
    // console.log statement to check whether this runs
    console.log(`width: ${width}, height: ${height}`)
  }
}, [data])
```

My return value is:

```
<div style={{ width, height }}></div>
```

The state is updated and I get the logs that indicate that the `width` and `height` have been updated from `0`, `0` to `1920`, `1080`. But the component width and height remain `0px`, `0px`.

Any idea why this is happening?

## Update

It was not related to react.
My server was returning string values instead of integers. Console log was printing the strings without quotes so I missed it.
Viewing the dimensions of the component in the developer tools showed me NaNpx, NaNpx.
Fixing the server side return value, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

react update state asynchronously so adding `console.log` after firing `setState` doesn't mean state updated. to check width and height change use `useEffect` hook like this :

```
useEffect(()=>console.log(height,width),[width,height])
```

this effect will fire each time height or width change.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. But the use effect was working fine. After further investigation, I found out that the server was returning width and height as a string. Since the style object only accepts px values as integers, my component was being rendered with NaNpx, NaNpx dimensions. Converting the values to numbers before setting them in useState fixed this issue. Apparently I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 <div style={{ width :`${width}px` ,height: `${height}px` }}></div>
```